# How to install easygui on Macbook Pro(macOS Sierra)?

Tags: python

I've searched & tried many ways to install easygui,but still, when I import easygui, python reminded me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import easygui
  File "easygui.py", line 1

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xff' in file easygui.py on line 2, but no 
encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

**So what should I do then? How to install easygui on my mac?**

------How I installed it-------

S1 Open up Terminal

S2 Type in  pip install easygui

S3 Terminal returns the message:

```
localhost:~ Fannn$ pip install easygui 
Collecting easygui
  Downloading easygui-0.98.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (90kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 13kB/s 
Installing collected packages: easygui
Successfully installed easygui-0.98.1
localhost:~ Fannn$
```

Answer (score 0):

theres a character in the easygui.py file. you'll have to edit it.